# Enable CORS for Subdomain ('www'), not just Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

When I try to POST my contact form I receive a console error that my Lambda, SES, API Gateway, Cloudfront alternate origin configuration won't work from the subdomain 'www.example.com', while it works from 'example.com'. How can I allow the contact form to avoid any issues on multiple (sub)domains? The error in console tells me the following:

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/rest/contact. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)."

My alternate Cloudfront origin catches '/rest/contact'. I've tested the Lambda function with API Gateway and SES - that works well. I've also enabled OPTIONS and CORS on API Gateway, which dismissed an earlier error. Using a wildcard on Route53, etc., hasn't done me any good either.

Any help is appreciated. I'm looking for a suggestion as to how to make my contact form as flexible as possible using these AWS services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lambda function to generate the CORS headers dynamically based the origin header you get from the request if you don't want to have `*` as the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`